# Zip archiving tool for auto backup of random files

Tags: backup, service, compression

I realise that I should probably be writing command scripts or something to do this but I'm just a fancy pants software developer who is helping out do some file backup so I want a fast and dirty solution. Sorry.

Is there a tool for taking full size files, zipping them up and putting them somewhere for an archiving service to hoover up on a schedule? I need it to run unattended and daily. I already have Super File Synchronizer which seems to zip things for transfer but as far as I can work out unzips the files after transfer automatically and doesn't offer an option to keep them zipped or generate pre-zipped backups. I could be wrong about this.

I will scour the instructions while this question is here and see if I am wrong but in case I am not, any alternatives?

P.S. if you know that writing a command script would be easier and don't mind writing me some instructions that is fine. I'm not averse, just ignorant.

Comment: What is your platform / OS?

Comment: Oh, sorry, Windows Server 2003

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I have used a batch file to compress with 7Zip on a Schedule.

This: http://www.computerhope.com/batch.htm

helped me with the writing of my first batch file.

And this http://www.codejacked.com/zip-up-files-from-the-command-line/

gave me a push with the 7-Zip bit.

Answer (score 1):

The [WinZip](http://www.winzip.com/win/en/index.htm) CLI should be able to do what you need. I use it in a scheduled batch file to zip up database backups.